# VC++ EXE standalone has bugs that don't happen in IDE

Tags: visual-c++, stdvector

My program has a very specific error that took me a while to track down - now I don't know how to fix it. My code is very long and in many files and I don't see much point in posting it here.

In the IDE, everything runs fine, in both Debug and Release (with the runtime library set to either /MTd or /MT, respectively, so I'm assuming all dependencies are included).

However, when I run the standalone, I get a crash. At first I thought it was a dependency problem but it doesn't seem so.

At some point in the code, I am accessing a vector via a method call: `t->GetList()`, where GetList is defined as `std::vector<T*> & GetList()` and the method simply returns a member variable (simply defined as `std::vector<T*> field` in the class).

It turns out, if I print out the size of the list while running from the IDE, I get 0 (which is the correct answer in this case).

However, when doing the same thing running from standalone, I get the size as 467467353.

I tried changing the method declaration to `std::vector<T*> * GetList()` and doing `return &field;` and updating the rest of the code but this didn't fix anything.

I then tried replacing the member variable `field` with a pointer, and in the constructor instantiating a new vector and deleting it in the destructor. Still no luck.

So I made a simple test case program that simply made a class with a vector field, and a method to return a reference to it. Then in `main` I would create an instance variable and getting the vector and printing the size. This worked both in VC++ and as a standalone - both returned zero.

This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out why I'm getting different behaviour. Why is the standalone running differently, and what should I be looking at to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing any files by relative path, by any chance? One difference between running form the IDE and standalone is that the current working directory is different. So files may be found in one case and not found in the other. If, on top of that, you don't do error checking on the outcome of file operations...

Comment: All files are accessed by absolute path. I even logged out every file that I read just to make sure. Anyway, even if they weren't, I'm running the standalone from it's normal compile location (at the moment anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it was literally a bug in my code that was very well hidden. I was dynamically casting to a wrong type.

Somehow it slipped past when I was running on Windows and OSX in both Debug and Release, and as a standalone on OSX. Good thing I found it.